# Python string .format(*variable)

Tags: python

I'm reading a book to read and it covers this below example.

```
somelist = list(SPAM)
parts = somelist[0], somelist[-1], somelist[1:3]
'first={0}, last={1}, middle={2}'.format(*parts)
```

Everything seems clear apart from the star being used at the end of the last line. The book fails to explain the usage of this and I hate to progress on without full understanding things.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's argument unpacking (kinda) operator.

```
args = [1, 2, 3]
fun(*args)
```

is the same as

```
fun(1, 2, 3)
```

(for some callable `fun`).

There's also star in function definition, which means "all other positional arguments":

```
def fun(a, b, *args):
    print('a =', a)
    print('b =', b)
    print('args =', args)

fun(1, 2, 3, 4) # a = 1, b = 2, args = [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 9):

The `*` operator, often called the star or splat operator, unpacks an iterable into the arguments of the function, so in this case, it's equivalent to:

```
'first={0}, last={1}, middle={2}'.format(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2])
```

[The python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) have more info.

Comment: Changed tuple to collection, because it works with any iterable. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @NiklasB. This is true, I was thinking about this case, but indeed, in general you can use any iterable. In fact, I'll change collection to iterable as they are not quite the same thing - you could also use a generator, for example.

Comment: Sure, I thought of collection as being the same as an iterable, but it makes more sense this way.

Comment: Thanks for such quick replies guys. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A comprehensive [explanation](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) about single and double asterisk form.

Answer (score 0):

`*` when used inside a function means that the `variable` following the `*` is an iterable, and it extracted inside that function.
here `'first={0}, last={1}, middle={2}'.format(*parts)` actually represents this:

```
'first={0}, last={1}, middle={2}'.format(parts[0],parts[1],parts[2])
```

**for example:**

```
 >>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
 >>> print(*a)
 1 2 3 4 5
```